# How to treat missing elements from certain pages when scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I need to scrape the code below from a range of product pages, and then split it to show the author and the illustrator separately.

The problem is:

Some pages have both the `<li>` for author and the `<li>` illustrator, as on page1

Certain pages have only the `<li>` for author, as on page2

Certain pages have neither author nor illustrator, so no `<ul>` at all, as on page3

The only way to know whether the `<li>` is for illustrator, is if the `<li>` contains the text "(Illustreerder)".

How can I assign default values to author and illustrator for when they are empty?

```
<ul class="product-brands">
    <li class="brand-item">
        <a href="https://lapa.co.za/Skrywer/zinelda-mcdonald-illustreerder.html" title="Zinelda McDonald (Illustreerder)">Zinelda McDonald (Illustreerder)</a>
    </li>
    <li class="brand-item">
        <a href="https://lapa.co.za/Skrywer/jose-reinette-palmer.html" title="Jose  Palmer &amp; Reinette Lombard">Jose  Palmer &amp; Reinette Lombard</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
}

# AUTHOR & ILLUSTRATOR
page1 = 'https://lapa.co.za/kinder-en-tienerboeke/leer-my-lees-vlak-r-grootboek-10-tippie-help-vir-frikkie'

# AUTHOR ONLY
page2 = 'https://lapa.co.za/catalog/product/view/id/1649/s/hoendervleis-grillerige-stories-en-rympies/category/84/'

# NO AUTHOR and NO ILLUSTRATOR
page3 = 'https://lapa.co.za/catalog/product/view/id/1633/s/sanri-steyn-7-vampiere-van-vlermuishoogte/category/84/'

# PAGE WITH NO STOCK
page4 = 'https://lapa.co.za/kinder-en-tienerboeke/my-groot-lofkleuterbybel-2-oudiomusiek'


illustrator = '(Illustreerder)'
productlist = []

r = requests.get(page2, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

isbn = soup.find('div', class_='value', itemprop='sku').text.replace(" ", "")
stocks = soup.find('div', class_='stock available')
if stocks is not None:
    stock = stocks.text.strip()
if stocks is None:
    stock = 'n/a'
 
for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'product-brands'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        author = litag.text.strip() or 'None'

        if illustrator not in author:
            author = author

for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'product-brands'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        author = litag.text.strip()

        if illustrator in author:
            illustrator = author
          
bookdata = [isbn, stock, author, illustrator]
print(bookdata)
```

Expected Output for:
`r = requests.get(page1, headers=headers)`

```
['9781776356515', 'In voorraad', 'Jose  Palmer & Reinette Lombard', 'Zinelda McDonald']
```

Expected Output for:
`r = requests.get(page2, headers=headers)`

```
['9780799383874', 'In voorraad', 'Jaco Jacobs', 'None']
```

Expected Output for:
`r = requests.get(page3, headers=headers)`

```
['9780799383690', 'In voorraad', 'None', 'None']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

- First select the `<ul>` that you need using `find()`

  ```
  ul = soup.find('ul', class_='product-brands')
  ```
- Now check if the `<ul>` exists. If `True` then you have atleast one of author or illustrator or both.
- If `True`, then get the strings of the `<li>` tags inside the `<ul>` element and return the list. You can use `.stripped_strings` to get a list of all the strings inside a tag.
- If `False` simply return `None`.

  ```
  if ul:
        return list(ul.stripped_strings)
  return None
  ```
- Based on the number of items in the list returned I think it is fairly easy to figure out what is what as you mentioned in the question that:

  > *The only way to know whether the `<li>` is for illustrator, is if the `<li>` contains the text "(Illustreerder)".*

**Here is the code that gives the list of author and Illustrator (If either of them exists) else `None`.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# AUTHOR & ILLUSTRATOR
page1 = 'https://lapa.co.za/kinder-en-tienerboeke/leer-my-lees-vlak-r-grootboek-10-tippie-help-vir-frikkie'

# AUTHOR ONLY
page2 = 'https://lapa.co.za/catalog/product/view/id/1649/s/hoendervleis-grillerige-stories-en-rympies/category/84/'

# NO AUTHOR and NO ILLUSTRATOR
page3 = 'https://lapa.co.za/catalog/product/view/id/1633/s/sanri-steyn-7-vampiere-van-vlermuishoogte/category/84/'

# PAGE WITH NO STOCK
page4 = 'https://lapa.co.za/kinder-en-tienerboeke/my-groot-lofkleuterbybel-2-oudiomusiek'


def test(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    ul = soup.find('ul', class_='product-brands')
    # Setting Default values for author and illustrator
    author, illustrator = None, None
    # Return a list only if ul is not None
    if ul:
        details = list(ul.stripped_strings)
        # Assigning the names to "author" and "illustrator"
        for name in details:
            if name.endswith('(Illustreerder)'):
                illustrator = name
            else:
                author = name
    return (author, illustrator)

    
# Iterate over the pages and call the test() function to get author and illustrator names
for page in [page1, page2, page3, page4]:
    author, illustrator = test(page)
    print(f'Authors: {author}\nIllustrators: {illustrator}\n')
```

Now, you have `author` and `illustrator` names separated out and stored in different variables for every page.

```
Authors: Jose  Palmer & Reinette Lombard
Illustrators: Zinelda McDonald (Illustreerder)

Authors: Jaco Jacobs
Illustrators: None

Authors: None
Illustrators: None

Authors: Jan de Wet
Illustrators: None
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I do however need to take it further so that I can assign a variable to each value, even if the value is none.

Comment: author =  and 
illustartor =

Comment: Yes. I left it for you to figure out yourself. Please upvote and accept if my answer helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you, im battling though, but hopefully will get it eventually.

Comment: I honesty tried for over 4 hours.  If anyone can shed some light, please :)

Comment: @SchalkJoubert I have updated my answer to seperate out the ```author``` and ```illustrator``` names and store them in variables.